# Python for loop with input using append( )

Tags: python, string, for-loop, input, append

```
beatles = []
print(beatles)

beatles.append("John Lennon")
beatles.append("Paul McCartney")
beatles.append("George Harrison")
print(beatles)'

for i in range(len(beatles): 
     beatles.append("Stu Sutcliffe")
     beatles.append("Pete Best")
```

Need help with the for loop using append()

Comment: Change `for i in range(len(beatles):` to `for i in range(len(beatles)):`. You missed the closing parenthesis

Comment: At least say what you're trying to do.

Comment: You don’t want the new Beatles you are trying to append to be hard-coded inside the for-loop. Where are the new Beatles stored? In another list (e.g. bugs) or are you getting them one by one from user input. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you.  Getting the names from user input.

Comment: Syntax error aside, you don't want to add Stu and Pete to the list 3 times (once for each other Beatle). You would probably want something like `for name in ["Stu Sutcliffe", "Pete Best"]: beatles.append(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Honestly not too sure what your asking for but to my understanding your looking for a way to add to a list using input then try this out for size.

You can replace list() with [] if you desire

```
beatles = list()
while True:
    inp = input("Add Name to list ")
    if inp == 'done' : break
    beatles.append(inp)

beatles.append("John Lennon")
beatles.append("Paul McCartney")
beatles.append("George Harrison")
print(beatles)
```